# AngularJS - How to use input field with strict search?

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling to find a way so that a user can input an Employee ID number into an input field and then have the table display only the relevant fields.

Right now my problem is that the ng-repeat filters display any id numbers "containing" the id number rather than the actual id number.

I've tried doing a strict search but must be doing it wrong. Heres my code sample:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ListAllUsersCtrl">
    <form align="center">
        <label>Enter user id: <input type="text" ng-model="search" id="search" placeholder="user id">
        </label><br>
    </form>

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-default table-striped table-bordered text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Amount</td>
                    <td>Reimb. ID</td>
                    <td>Receipt</td>
                    <td>Author</td>
                    <td>Solved</td>
                    <td>Submit</td>
                    <td>Type</td>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Resolver</td>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in reimb | filter:{'reimb_Author': search}">
                    <td>{{ x.reimb_Amount | currency}}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.reimb_Id }}</td>
                    <td>{{x.reimb_Receipt}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.reimb_Author}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.reimb_Solved}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.reimb_Submit}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.reimb_Type}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.reimb_Status_ID}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.reimb_Description}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.reimb_Resolver}}</td>   
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are nearly there just add the following to the filter :true so it looks like filter:{'reimb_Author': search}: true (true ist for strict)

Comment: That didn't work for some reason..

Comment: Instead, you can try: `ng-if='x.reimb_Author == search'`